# Batch For loop "was unexpected at this time."

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am having an issue running this batch file, it seems to be hung up at my For loop and tells me the following:

> `\%y\%m` was unexpected at this time

Here is my code:

```
 FOR %%y IN (2014) DO (
    ECHO %%y
    FOR %%m IN (Jan Feb Mar) DO (
       IF EXIST %~dp0%%Y\%%m (
            ECHO Applying updates for %%m %%y
            FOR %%f IN ("%~dp0%%y\%%m\*.*") DO (
                ECHO Installing "%%~ff"
                   WUSA "%%~ff" /quiet /norestart
)
)
)
```

Any ideas on why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Loop variables are case-sensitive, so you need to replace `%%Y` with `%%y`.

Also consider using quotes: `IF EXIST "%~dp0%%y\%%m" (`

Comment: I added the quotes as recommended and changed all to lowercase but not it says "The Syntax of the command is incorrect"

Comment: I don't see such error, but 1) your code block lacks a closing `)`. Consider indenting the parentheses to make the structure more obvious. And 2) that error message could be emitted by `WUSA`. Comment out any `echo off` you have in your batch file to debug it.